# Tweets, Location, Keywords and Data

Tags: twitter, location, foursquare

I'm trying do some analysis on locations where people are going during winters. The approach I'm following is get tweets from a specific city (say, New York) and with the keyword `Foursquare`. Then use foursquare data for that user to see his/her checkins and try to trace a pattern.

So, I'm stuck in the first phase. How do I get those tweets from ONE city and with the keyword FOURSQUARE. I'm not sure if I understood how to use streaming API correctly and the ReST API isn't working (shows NOT AUTHORISED)

Could you tell me a detailed procedure for a rookie to understand the process of doing the above mentioned process. Also, let me know if you have a better approach for analysing trends in check ins.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to read these:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/platform-objects/places

You can give Twitter a latitude/longitude coordinate and a radius, or you can use the "place" field as a filter. Either way, expect to fine-tune this a bit to fit your needs. You also need to take into account that a lot of people might tweet without location services enabled.

If you want to use the REST API, you need to get an API key from twitter.

Comment: hey..wont the v1.1 of this API work? Coz I'm trying to do that with the API key I got from twitter but it aint working.. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets

Comment: I would recommend talking to twitter and getting your API key to work, because you will be rate-limited without one. Twitter is increasingly restricting features in the public API as well.